# How can I extend/override admin create order controller?

Tags: enterprise-1.14

I am trying to override adminhtml_sales_order_create controller.
I have created a small module 
***app/code/local/PA/Sales/etc/config.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <PA_Sales>
            <version>0.1</version>
        </PA_Sales>
    </modules>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <sales before="Mage_Adminhtml">PA_Sales_Adminhtml</sales> 
                    </modules>
               </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

and created controller file as

***app/code/local/PA/Sales/controllers/Adminhtml/CreateorderController.php***

```
<?php
require_once 'Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/CreateController.php';
    class PA_Sales_Adminhtml_CreateorderController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_CreateController
    {
         public function indexAction()
        {
                 echo "something";exit;
        }
    }
```

I am unable to override this controller, where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to put your controller in 
`app/code/local/PA/Sales/controllers/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/CreateorderController.php` and name your class accordingly.
As a general rule, when rewriting a controller from  `Mage/Adminhtml/Some/Controller/HereController.php` your new path should be 
`Namespace/Module/controllers/Adminhtml/Some/Controller/HereController.php`.
So what comes after `Adminhtml` in the original controller should be kept after `Adminhtml` in your custom controller.